# How to use the `vcconv` command in lme4 for serial correlation?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm working with a large longitudinal dataset of firm-year observations.  For some time now I have been using `lme4`to implement crossed (non-nested) effects for year and firm-ID groups.

My goal is now to correct for the serial correlation in the firm-group dimension.  Based on chl's and fabians' answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models) (as well as Ben Bolker's comment on the latter), I've assumed this is impossible with `lmer()`, but is feasible with `nlme::lme()`.

I have been able to implement crossed effects in `nlme` based on the discussion in Pinheiro & Bates (2000, sec. 4.2.2, pp. 163-6).  In principle then, I believe I can use the `correlation = AR1()` speficiation in `lme()` to control for autocorrelation.

My strong preference, however, would be to implement such a correlation specification in `lmer()` because:

1. `lme4` is much, much (much) faster
2. `nlme` requires crossed effects to be nested in some higher group -- without such a higher level grouping I'm forced to create an arbitrary dummy for `groupedData` to which **all** observations belong (e.g., [here](https://biostatmatt.com/archives/2718)).  This creates issues interpreting the relative levels of variation between the two crossed groups and the residual variance because some of the variation appears to be captured by the higher-level dummy group.

I got excited when I found the feature request [#224](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/224) on GitHub, but alas it doesn't seem like there's much movement on the flexLambda front (please let me know if I'm wrong!).

### lme4 v1.1-10

I've just noticed that the latest (Oct. 2015) version of `lme4` contains a `vcconv` command that can

> Convert between representation of (co-)variance structures (EXPERIMENTAL.)

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/vcconv.R), it seems that *maybe* the `sdcor2cov` option could allow one to specify a correlation structure such as AR(1).

So my questions are:

1. Is this interpretation of the `vcconv` function correct?
2. If so, does the user supply the correlation (e.g., AR(1)) parameters or are they determined internally in `lmer()`?
3. How does one implement this function properly?

Comment: I do mean to get to this one of these days soon.  Unfortunately `vcconv` does *not* do what you want; it's just for converting between log-Cholesky, variance-covariance, and std dev-correlation scale. https://rpubs.com/bbolker/6298 has *some* information on this topic, but it's mostly just a brain dump ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the confirmation. I thought I was being overly optimistic in my interpretation of vcconv.  And, after posting this question, I found the clear statement in the lme4 documentation that is "does _not_ currently implement nlme’s features for modeling heteroscedasticity and correlation".  Anyhow, I'm looking forward to having more control over the VarCov matrices!  It's a great package.  Thanks.